# jquery bind on images?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've an img and a button, and I'd like to use jQuery bind to respond to onclick events. Bind works on the input button, but not on img. Here is my JavaScript code:

```
function drawDetails (event) {
    var id=0;
    if ((typeof $(this).attr('id')) !== 'undefined') {
        id = parseInt($(this).attr('id').replace(/[^0-9]+/g,''));
    } else if((typeof e.id)!=='undefined') {
        id = e.id;
    }
    alert("drawDetails " + id);
}

$("input[id^=camera-]").bind('click', drawDetails);
$("input[id^=details-]").bind('click', drawDetails);
```

HTML:

```
<img id="camera-10" src="camera.gif"/>
<input id="details-10" type="button" value="Details 10">

<img id="camera-11" src="camera.gif"/>
<input id="details-11" type="button" value="Details 11">
```

I've prepared a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eJ3rn/2/) of it. How can I make the event fire also when the image is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `img` instead of `input`:

```
$("img[id^=camera-]").bind('click', drawDetails);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eJ3rn/3/)

Comment: man! how silly, I am! Thank you, first time to use bind and I didn't notice.

Comment: this works too: `$("img[id^=camera-],input[id^=details-]").bind('click', drawDetails);`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$("img[id^=camera-]").bind('click', drawDetails);
$("input[id^=details-]").bind('click', drawDetails);
```

example
http://jsfiddle.net/eJ3rn/4/